# Determine if an element is block level or inline with JavaScript while walking DOM tree

Tags: javascript, html, dom

While walking HTML5 DOM tree I want to determine whether each element is a block level element or inline element.

```
var divElement = document.getElementById('foo');
alert(divElement.style.display)
alert(window.getComputedStyle(divElement, null).getPropertyValue('display'))
```

I see that the first alert displays a null-string while the second alert displays 'block', so I think the second technique is what I need to use. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UaFpv/

I want to know if there is any downside to using ​`window.getComputedStyle(divElement, null).getPropertyValue('display')` to do my job, like cross-browser compatibility issues, etc. Are there any other techniques that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old IE versions do not support `getComputedStyle`. For IE, use the [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property:

```
divElement.currentStyle['display'];
```

Implemented in your code:

```
var divElement = document.getElementById('foo');
var displayStyle;
if (divElement) { // Only if the element exists
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(divElement, null).getPropertyValue('display');
    } else {
        displayStyle = divElement.currentStyle.display;
    }
}
alert(displayStyle);
```